# Beamer layout for half page presentation

Tags: beamer, presentations

is there a specific beamer layout for producing slides mostly on the left handisde (except for title) in order to make handwritten annotations with a tablet (e.g. math derivations and so forth) on the right hand-side during lectures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To free up space on the right hand site, you could place your frame content in a `column` environment.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
        \begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
            \lipsum[2]
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]